# Why is there no git repository after installing etckeeper?

Tags: git, ubuntu-11.10, etckeeper, etc

I installed `etckeeper` on my ubuntu 11.10 server, and after creating the etckeeper repository with:

```
etckeeper init
etckeeper commit "Initial version"
```

I got the error:

> ```
> bzr: ERROR: No changes to commit. Please 'bzr add' the files you want to commit, or use --unchanged to force an empty commit.
> ```

So I added a test file and then I could create the etckeeper repository:

```
touch /etc/test
etckeeper commit "Initial version"
rm /etc/test
```

But still there seems to be no git repository there:

```
cd /etc
git status
```

How can I use git to watch changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out:

in the config-file `etckeeper/etckeeper.conf` You have to set

```
VCS="git"
#VCS="bzr"
```

then again:

```
etckeeper init
etckeeper commit "Initial version"
```

Then everything works on git:

```
cd /etc
git status
```

Answer (score 3):

I hit the same issue on 14.04, however it was a bit more annoying as the package was initializing etckeeper using bazaar automatically on apt-get install.

Switching to git in the config file as mentioned above wasn't enough; I first had to undo the bazaar setup which was done at install time, like this:

```
etckeeper uninit
```

The steps above then worked fine.